# Silverstripe extensions not registering

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've got a simple extension which I'm planning to use in order to add extra fields.

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;


class ColumnExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $db = [
        'SectionID' => 'Varchar(255)'
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        dd('sdsd');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Content', TextField::create('SectionID', 'Section ID'), 'SubHeading');
    }
}
```

And I've added the below to a yml file in the app/_config folder

```
PackageNameSpace\Blocks\Column:
  extensions:
    - ColumnExtension
```

FYI: I haven't added any namespacing. I've got a few other extensions working without the namespacing.
My issue is that my extension doesn't seem to be registering. The code doesn't seem to reach the dd() command.

Comment: Does the `PackageNameSpace\Blocks\Column` class either directly call `$this->extend('updateCMSFields')` or else call `parent::getCMSFields()`? If not, that explains it.

Another thing to check is if your config is actually sticking - check `/dev/config` in your browser and search for the config you've defined. If it's not there you may have forgotten to flush

Comment: Thanks @GuySartorelli. Will keep this in mind the next time. I've just used an alternative way before. I've seen the updateCMSFields and getCMSFields methods used. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: `updateCMSFields()` only does anything inside a subclass of `SilverStripe\Core\Extension` applied to a `DataObject`. `getCMSFields()` only does anything inside a subclass of `DataObject` directly.